# App not working on iPod but does work on iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipod

I didn't test my app on iPods before submitting to the app store.
Now I'm getting comments that the app doesn't work on iPods (doesn't even load, just crashes immediately).
The app uses the user location, but from what I understood the iPod also is able to find locations although he doesn't have a GPS.
Does anyone have an idea what might be wrong? What can cause an app to work on iPhones but not on iPods?

How can I set that iPods won't see my app on the app store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably calling methods that are not supported on the device.

If you are making a call to something that simply doesn't exist on the device it will crash.

For example, in one of my applications I use the iPhone4 LED light, if i try to call that on a device that does not have it, it crashes my app.

So i have to put a catch in, so that if the device isn't an iPhone4, it does something else.

---

Something else that has crossed my mind, when i tried to build for an iPod Touch for a friend, i had to set the Base SDK as 3.2, otherwise it would not install onto the device correctly, this is possibly due to his iPod not being upto date, but he told me it was.. Just a thought.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You gave me a direction to look into. I'm calling Location Services in my app. Do you think this might cause the problem?

Comment: Can you direct me to such a "try catch" example?

Comment: try looking at this code http://github.com/erica/uidevice-extension/ by Erica Saddun